# numpy 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, error-handling, conda

Im on windows 11, Im trying to run my code that involves numpy, but I keep getting the same error  'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/521f2.png)

I have tried everything (by researching). Like changing python interpreters (conda,microsoft)

[Lists of interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLtUL.png)

for some reason in interpreters for msys, the vsc detects the numpy as a problem while the other interpreters dont. but I still get the same error for all of them.

Ive also tried reinstalling numpy and this is the result i always get.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9oRG.png)

I hope you guys can help me out on solving this problem! Do take note I also have ubuntu linux(another version for python) as a vm I use for school installed(idk if thats relevant). I also changed a few things in environment variables if thats important in finding the solution.

Comment: What if you install using `python3 -m pip install numpy` instead ?

Comment: Yup, I tried that, it didnt work because of this cmake error. I tried installing it from the official website. Still didnt work

Comment: There are multiple python interpreters in your environment, have you tried to check each one and run the python scripts? I‘m not sure which interpreter you are installing `numpy` in according to the installation path of pip.